# Interactive copy paste from one excel to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to copy paste the content from one excel to another . However no data is being copied. 
Please help.

```
Sub foo3()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant

path1 = Application.GetOpenFilename()
path2 = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(path1)
Set y = Workbooks.Open(path2)

'Store the value in a variable:
vals = x.Sheets("sheetname").Range("B1:B6").Value

'Use the variable to assign a value to the other file/sheet:
y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1:A6").Value = vals

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to 

solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What i want is: 1) Ask user to select an excel file. 2) copy data from a required column. 3) Ask user to select another excel file where he want to save it. 4) And paste the copied data from first excel

Comment: FWIW - Your code works for me.  Are you sure you had data in cells B1:B6 of the first file you opened?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub foo3()

Dim x as Workbook
Dim y as Workbook
Dim xName as String
Dim yName as String

xName = Application.GetOpenFileName()
yName = Application.GetOpenFileName()

Set x = Workbooks.Open(xName)
Set y = Workbooks.Open(yName)

y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1:A6").Value = x.Sheets("sheetname").Range("B1:B6").Value

x.Close

End Sub
```

I hope this works.

Else, try this one:

```
Sub foo3()

Dim x as Workbook
Dim y as Workbook
Dim xName as String
Dim yName as String

xName = Application.GetOpenFileName()
yName = Application.GetOpenFileName()

Set x = Workbooks.Open(xName)
Set y = Workbooks.Open(yName)

x.Sheets("sheetname").Range("B1:B6").Cells.Copy y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1:A6").Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I understood your question, I came up with this solution. If this isn't solving your query, kindly elaborate your problem briefly.

Comment: Thank you.The script  runs fine but only problem is data is not getting copied at all.

Comment: It's missing a " in the range A1:A6.

Comment: Yaa, i corrected it and after that only ran the script, but the data was not getting copied.

Comment: Hi both, thank you for the help, the code works fine. (I did some cosmetic mistake in my  code)